# DirectSound ErrorCode DSERR_ACCESSDENIED(0x80070005)

Tags: directsound

Firstly my english is not good. sorry!

when i call directsound method.

HRESULT hr = IDirectSoundBuffer8->Play(0,0,0);

return code is DSERR_ACCESSDENIED(0x80070005)

What is the meaning of return code DSERR_ACCESSDENIED in directsound?
when does it occur?

Comment: First, what version of Windows? Second, is your buffer a primary or secondary buffer? What cooperative level have you set? Lastly, have you considered using something less ancient like [Xaudio2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415813.aspx)?

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn 1. Windows7 32bit 2. Secondary buffer. 3. DSSCL_PRIORITY. 4. No